# MYSQL INSERT INTO syntax error

Tags: mysql

I would like to insert a new row in the following table:

```
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| index             | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| exports_fields_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| exports_id        | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Therefor I tried the following sql statement:

```
INSERT INTO 'exports_has_export_fields' ('index', 'exports_fields_id', 'exports_id') VALUES (0, 78, 3);
```

But then I get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''exports_has_export_fields' ('index', 'exports_fields_id', 'exports_id') VALUES ' at line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using single quotes, but you need backticks (`) to refer to fields  or tables whose name may conflict with MySQL reserved keywords.

In this case, just `index` is a reserved one, even though you can backtick everything for safety sake.

So you can say:

```
INSERT INTO `exports_has_export_fields` (`index`, `exports_fields_id`, `exports_id`) VALUES (0, 78, 3);
            ^                         ^  ^     ^  ^                 ^  ^          ^
```

or just

```
INSERT INTO exports_has_export_fields (`index`, exports_fields_id, exports_id) VALUES (0, 78, 3);
                                       ^     ^
```

From [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/1983854):

> Backticks are to be used for table and column identifiers, but are
>   only necessary when the identifier is a [MySQL reserved
>   keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html),
>   or when the identifier contains whitespace characters or characters
>   beyond a limited set (see below) It is often recommended to avoid
>   using reserved keywords as column or table identifiers when possible,
>   avoiding the quoting issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with (edit with backticks)

```
INSERT INTO `exports_has_export_fields` (`index`, `exports_fields_id`, `exports_id`) VALUES (0, 78, 3);
```

There shouldn't be single quotes on table and column names.

If you are inserting in all Columns of a Table you can shorten your Insert statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO exports_has_export_fields VALUES (0, 78, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer with the shorter statement. The one above fails aswell. Only the shorten statement insert a new row. You know with it fails?

Comment: @user3205343 : try it with the backticks as mentioned in the answers above.

Comment: this doesn't work because `index` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the single quotes from your table name and fields?

```
INSERT INTO exports_has_export_fields (`index`, exports_fields_id, exports_id) VALUES (0, 78, 3);
```

Or if you want to shorten your query, try

```
INSERT INTO exports_has_export_fields VALUES (0, 78, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

`index` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html). Quote it (with backticks).

So you should use backticks quotes ` instead of single quotes '.

```
INSERT INTO `exports_has_export_fields` (`index`, `exports_fields_id`, `exports_id`) VALUES (0, 78, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think field `index` is primary key and it not zero
try

```
SET sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
```

before inserting the 0 value.